# How to style HTML elements passed into MDXRenderer?

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby

i'm building a blog with gatsbyjs where blog posts are `.md` files and are statically rendered as HTML pages. i've managed to style the `title, date, and published` data, but anything under the `---` is in times new roman. i've looked everywhere for inline styling tags for MDXRenderer but have had no luck. is this supported and if not, how can i style my body content? thanks!

**index.md**

```
---
title: Third Post!
date: 2020-09-10
published: true
---

This is my third post!

How my achievements mock me! -William Shakespeare
```

**index.md**

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { MDXRenderer } from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx'
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.js"

const Body = styled.body`
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DBDCE0;
    height: 100%;
`

const Heading1 = styled.h1`
    font-family: Arial;
`

const Paragraph = styled.p`
    font-family: Arial;
`

const ApplyButton = styled.button`
    background-color: #EC1B2F; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
`

export const query = graphql`
    query PostsByID($id: String!) {
        mdx(
            id: { eq: $id }
        ){
            body
            frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "YYYY MMMM DD")
            }
        }
    }
`

export default ({ data }) => {
    const { frontmatter, body } = data.mdx
    return (
        <Body>
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <Heading1>{frontmatter.title}</Heading1>
            <Paragraph>{frontmatter.date}</Paragraph>
            <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
            <ApplyButton>Apply</ApplyButton>
        </div>
        </Body>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to add a wrapper around `MDXRenderer`.

Here's an example using styled components:

```js
const MarkdownWrapper = styled.div`
  p {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }
  a {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.black};
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.black};
  }
 …
`;

…

<MarkdownWrapper>
  <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
</MarkdownWrapper>
```